# facebook graph api using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using this code to get the posts of a page in api in javascript but it isn't working the FUNCTION FB.API IS NOT BEING INVOKED.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.9'

});
```

};

(function(d, s, id){

```
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}

 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;

 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";

 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
```

}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function abdul(){

```
alert('working');
```

FB.api('EuropeanCommission/posts', GET, function(response) {

```
        var output="<ul>";

    for (var i in mydata.data) {

        output+="<li>"+mydata.data[i].message;

    }

    output+="</ul>";

    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;   });

};
```

Comment: Where do you call abdul?

Comment: when pressing button on simple html page

Comment: Please format the code properly. And then, as already advised in the FB developers group - check the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put param field in your api call and GET should be in the single quote ' ':

```
FB.api('EuropeanCommission/posts', GET, function(response) {      

});
```

You should do:

```
FB.api('EuropeanCommission/posts', 'GET', {} , function(response) {      

    });
```